# Git fails to launch Vim in Cygwin

Tags: vim, git, cygwin, vimdiff

I have Git working with Vim in a Powershell environment on my work laptop (Windows 7). It pops up Vim when I commit or use my `git vimdiff` alias.

I have attempted the same setup under Cygwin (being a Unix guy at heart) but when I type `git commit` or `git vimdiff`, Vim does not pop up; seemingly, though, Git is waiting on Vim because the action never completes until I <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> (after which it takes a minute or so to recover). I can commit with inline commit messages (`git commit -m "I would rather type this in Vim"`) and I can launch Vim/Vimdiff from the terminal with `vim` and `vimdiff`. I have my editor set to Vim in multiple places:

```
$ echo $EDITOR
vim
$ git config --get core.editor
vim
```

(Initially, I had not explicitly set it in Git, but only in the environment variable, and still had the same problem.)

It appears that I am running Windows Git in Cygwin. Being new to Cygwin, I did not realize this when I first asked the question. I could see how that might cause problems, but after playing around I have not yet been able to fix it.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: did you try setting full path to vim in git config or $EDITOR?

Comment: @skarface Ah: I did in Git, but forgot to go back and do it in EDITOR. Let me try...

Comment: @skarface It looks like `core.editor` has [higher priority](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596819/834176) than `EDITOR`, so I'm going to stick to modding that. I guess I haven't figured out what the correct full path is for Cygwin Vim though from the perspective of Windows Git running within Cygwin... or do I want to use Windows Vim?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @skarface, I have solved this problem with respect to commiting. First, as I mentioned in the edit to the question, it turned out I was not running Cygwin Git in Cygwin but actual Windows Git. Thus the integration issue makes sense: it is not finding `vim` or `vimdiff`.

I had to do:

```
git config --global core.editor C:/cygwin/bin/vim.exe
```

I am not sure why the above worked, since:

```
$ which vim
/usr/bin/vim
```

but:

```
$ ls C:/cygwin/usr/bin
ls: cannot access C:/cygwin/usr/bin: No such file or directory
```

So not sure exactly why that is the path that worked, but it did.

---

I have now solved it with respect to diffing as well. I had to:

```
$ git config --global diff.tool vimdiff
$ git config --global difftool.vimdiff.cmd  'C:/cygwin/bin/vim.exe -d "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"'
```

This allowed me to start Vimdiff with Git, but there were still some hickups. I could view the files, but the tool itself was failing to diff, giving these errors:

[image: diff errors]

It looks like what was happening here is that Git was somehow screwing with Vim's `shell` option. In my `.vimrc`, I put this command:

```
set shell=bash
```

and now everything works smoothly.

Comment: On Cygwin, `/bin` and `/usr/bin` are one and the same, but Windows doesn't know that and only sees the "real" `C:\cygwin\bin`.  That being said, for better integration, you're better off using Cygwin's `git` package.

Comment: @Yaakov: yeah, probably would be better off with Cygwin Git. The nice thing about using the Windows Git though is that I can do Git-TFS commands with it. When I originally posted the question I didn't realize I was using Windows Git.

Comment: perfect.  that worked for me.  +1